# Parallel Pipelining - Large Vectors

Tags: performance, vector, parallel-processing

Could someone explain the pipeline concept relating to large vectors to me?

I've found the following graph relating the speedup considering the vector length. This behavior is given, when the vectors length is larger then the length of the vector register. I don't unsterstand the occurrence of the saw tooths ... Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Can you give the source of this? Or can you give other details: for instance what is the performed vector operation, on which architecture type? Performance discontinuities usually happen because one of the caches cannot contain the whole input data at some point when you raise the vector size. I don't get how it is related to pipelining however.

Comment: On modern processors (and many old systems) there are vector instructions (e.g., [AVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)) that can perform operations on contiguous, aligned chunks of data faster than doing the operations one-at-a-time, so you get a higher (effective) floating-point operation per second doing vector operations than scalar.  So if you have (say) 64-byte vector processing widths, you get your highest effective FLOPS or MIPS rate processing data in 64-byte chunks.  Remaining items are processed one at a time at a lower MIPS rate, bringing down the average.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I agree but why would you get higher MIPS for the operation on a 64-elements vector than on a 60 elements vector. I though the maximum vector register size for SIMD instructions would be 512bits (ie 8 doubles). Is Vector Lenght given in bits or bytes or doubles?

Comment: @Emilien - Yup. Clearly the diagram is trying to point out some feature at vector lengths of 64 somethings, and until the OP replies to your questions, that's about all we know.